# android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity missing action bar

Tags: android

I am using the support library android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity to create Fragment based activities.

Since Lollipop I am now missing my action bar in all fragment based activities. I am wondering is this something to do with activities now inheriting from actionbaractivity?

I list below my manifest, activity and fragment xml and hope someone can tell me why this is happening. The design screens all show the title bar but it is missing on emulator and actual device runs.

First of all here is my fragment activity class that I extend for each activity, followed by my xml files:

**SingleFragmentActivity.java:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = createFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="safecontact.net.savemenow" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_fragment.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_appt.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:weightSum="1">
... REST OF FRAGMENT LAYOUT CUT FOR BREVITY
```

In design view the action bar and title etc are clearly visible, but when I run on the emulator the action bar is totally missing and only the activity view (with fragment) is rendered.

I hope someone can help with this as it is driving me mad. I am convinced it is something to do with the fact that I am using the support library for my fragments. Or maybe it is a theme issue?

Thanks.

EDIT: styles.xml listed as requested:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

.

Comment: Please post the definition of `AppTheme`.

Comment: Where is AppTheme please? I am not aware of that file

Comment: Your manifest has `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in the `<application>` element. Usually, that is defined in `res/values/styles.xml`, or other `styles.xml` files in related resource sets (e.g., `res/values-v11/styles.xml`).

Comment: I have edited my question to add the styles.xml file - I hope this is what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AppTheme` is inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`. For that to work, you *must* inherit from `AppCompatActivity`. Since `AppCompatActivity` itself inherits from `FragmentActivity`, most of your existing code should be fine. The only stuff that would need to change is anything related to the action bar, such as:

- Use `getSupportActionBar()`, rather than `getActionBar()`, to get the `ActionBar` object
- Use attributes in a custom namespace (e.g., `app`) where needed (e.g., `app:showAsAction`) instead of the `android` namespace (e.g., `android:showAsAction`) in menu resources

Note that in older versions `ActionBarActivity` had been used, which has been declared deprecated.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the theme instead of having to change all my code? Changing the inheritance away from v4 support library FragmentActivity would mean a major change. If I can just change the apptheme then I would be much happier with that. Thanks for your answer! I am a beginner and finding android a bit of a nightmare to learn ;)

Comment: @tentimes: "Changing the inheritance away from v4 support library FragmentActivity would mean a major change" -- it should be a handful of characters per activity class. "If I can just change the apptheme then I would be much happier with that" -- the simplest starting point would be to eliminate the `android:theme` attribute in `<application>` and delete the file that defines `AppTheme`. Along the way, get rid of your dependency on `appcompat-v7` and clean up anything else from it that you are using.

Comment: To be clearer, what I meant is that if I inherit from ActionBarActivity I lose support for earlier versions of Android (2.3). I am currently using the support library version of FragmentActivity, v4, which allows my app to be compatible with earlier versions of android.

Comment: @tentimes: "I inherit from ActionBarActivity I lose support for earlier versions of Android (2.3)" -- nonsense. As I wrote in my answer, `ActionBarActivity` **inherits from** `FragmentActivity`. Now, `ActionBarActivity` only works back to API Level 7 (Android 2.1), whereas `FragmentActivity` works back to API Level 4 (Android 1.6). Few active devices are running Android 2.0 or Android 1.6.

Comment: Ah I see. I did not understand that it went to API level 7, sorry. I am away for a couple of hours but will try this out when I get back and see what it does and report back. Hopefully this will solve my problem. Please keep in mind I am a beginner ;)

Comment: @tentimes: "Please keep in mind I am a beginner" -- if you had said "I think that I lose support" or "will I lose support?", you would have indicated that you are not certain about the behavior. Instead, you made a declaration ("I lose support"), one that in this case was incorrect. That being said, I apologize for reacting perhaps too harshly. BTW, for the Android Support package libraries, the `-v7` or `-v4` or whatever in the library name indicates how far back it works in terms of API levels.

Comment: Changing to inheriting from ActionBarActivity (from v7 support lib) instead of FragmentActivity (v4 support lib) works. Thank you! I have learned another couple of new things from this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use support Toolbar for Lollipop instead of ActionBar

Comment: I am not using it at all - I an inheriting from FragmentActivity in the support library.